# use pandas to tet previous year sales in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table from different companies' sales.

```
company_name sales  year
    A         200   2019
    A         100   2018
    A         30    2017
    B         15    2019
    B         30    2018
    B         45    2017
```

Now, I want to add a previous year's sales in the same row just like

```
company_name sales  year   previous_sales
    A         200   2019      100
    A         100   2018      30
    A         30    2017      Nan
    B         15    2019      30
    B         30    2018      45
    B         45    2017      Nan
```

I tried to use the code like this, but I failed to get the right result

```
df["previous_sales"] = df.groupby(['company_name', 'year'])['sales'].shift()
```

Comment: Check `df["previous_sales"] = df.groupby('company_name')['sales'].shift(-1)`

Comment: Please post the dataframe wich contains the previous sales.